# Google Directory API - Cannot pass nextPageToken (Google Admin SDK API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, pagination, google-api-nodejs-client

I have an issue with paginating results of `chromeosdevices.list` using the [Google directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/list).
I am a super admin in our Google workspace environment, have all the proper permissions, and can successfully pull up to 300 devices in our environment using the `chromeosdevices.list` method. The problem is that's only the first page of what we have (several thousand), and I need to pull attributes from all of them.

Here's my code, excuse all the console.logs and local creds, this is just a test at the moment :)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

let pageToken;
let allDevices = [];
let counter = 1;

async function loadData() {

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "credentials.json",
    scopes: [ 
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos"
    ],
    clientOptions: {
      subject: "admin@myDomain.com"
    }
  });

  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const googleAdminDir = await google.admin({ version: "directory_v1", auth: client });
  const directory = google.admin({ version: 'directory_v1', auth });

  do {

    const deviceData = await googleAdminDir.chromeosdevices.list({
      customerId: "myIdHere",
      maxResults: 100,
      fields: "chromeosdevices(annotatedAssetId,osVersion,osUpdateStatus,lastKnownNetwork),nextPageToken",
      pageToken: pageToken,
      response: { raw: true }
    });

    const newPageToken = deviceData.data.nextPageToken || response.nextPageToken;

    if (deviceData.data.chromeosdevices) {
      allDevices = allDevices.concat(deviceData.data.chromeosdevices);
    }
    if (deviceData.data.nextPageToken !== pageToken) {
      console.log(`Current token is ${pageToken}`);
      console.log(`Retrieved token is ${newPageToken}`);
      console.log("Page token is different than what is already stored. Updating....");
      pageToken = newPageToken;
    }
    else { pageToken = null; }

    console.log(`${deviceData.data.chromeosdevices.length} results found on ${counter} page of data. Processing...`);

    counter ++;
    pageToken = newPageToken;

  } while (pageToken);

  return allDevices;
}
loadData().then((data) =>{
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err =>{ console.error(err); });
```

Every loop, I grab the `nextPageToken` from the response, and put it into the `pageToken` variable. Then I pass that `nextPageToken` back into the loop, and it's supposed to work. The problem is that **every time**, I get the same `nextPageToken`. This makes me think I possibly have my async messed up, but I'm scratching my head as to where the error is. I'll also always never discount the possibility that I'm doing everything completely wrong :)

Does anyone have sharper eyes than me?